# Python script to read CSVs and regroup it into the data types I need

Tags: python, performance, csv, hash-map, iterator

This code does the following:

1. Read CSV file and determine `sub_type` based on `series_desc`.
2. Turn row into dictionaries `new_person` and `new_subscriptions`.
3. Check list `people` for the `new_person` and add the person if it is actually new.
4. Check each `person` in the list `people` for the `new_subscription` and add it if it is not there.

My desired output is a list of dictionaries called people. A dictionary in people might look like this:

```
{'id': group_id, 'subscriptions': [sub_dict1, sub_dict2]}
```

where a sub_dict looks like this:

```
{'id': sub_id, 'season': season_desc, 'sub_type': sub_type}
```

The code:

```
import csv

people = []

#open csv file
csv_file = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'))

#read CSV file into a list of people
for record in csv_file:
    sub_id = record[0]
    group_id = record[6]
    season_desc = record[11]
    series_desc = record[12]
    price = record[13]

    if "MW" in series_desc:
        sub_type = "Masterworks"
    elif "Pops" in series_desc:
        sub_type = "Pops"
    elif "Chamber" in series_desc:
        sub_type = "Chamber"

    new_person = {'id': group_id}
    new_subscription = {'id': sub_id, 'season': season_desc, 'sub_type': sub_type}

    #if this is the first time through the loop
    if len(people) == 0:
        new_person['subscriptions'] = []
        new_person['subscriptions'].append(new_subscription)
        people.append(new_person)

    #if this is not the first time through the loop
    else:
        #check if this person has already been recorded
        if any(person['id'] == new_person['id'] for person in people) == True:
            #check if this subscription has already been added to this person
            #use enumerate to get a key to search people
            for i in enumerate(people):
                if i[1]['id'] == new_person['id']:
                    key = i[0]

                    if any(sub['id'] == new_subscription['id'] for sub in people[key]['subscriptions']) == True:
                        pass
                else:
                    people[key]['subscriptions'].append(new_subscription)

        #if not, add the subscription to them and save the person
        else:
            new_person['subscriptions'] = []
            new_person['subscriptions'].append(new_subscription)
            people.append(new_person)
```

The challenge: It is REALLY slow.

I have `for`/`if`/`else` loops nested inside `for`/`if`/`else` loops, so I am sure that is the cause. What can I do differently?

Comment: How much data are you going through that this is noticeably slow?

Comment: About 55,000 records, currently. We add about 3-4K annually, also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The opened file is never closed, a better habit is to use
  `with open(filename, 'rb') as foo:`.
- `foo == True` is rarely needed; unless you really need to
  differentiate between `True`/`False` and the various other truthy
  values it's easier just to test for the variable instead.  Same goes
  for the empty list for that matter.
- The `pass` doesn't do anything; `price` is unused.
- Instead of linear search you could keep a `set` or `dict` of already
  recorded people around.
- With `enumerate` it's easier to destructure the result directly in the
  loop; that said, the `enumerate` is also not necessary here.
- The use of `key` looks buggy:  In the `else` branch it has never been
  set (except maybe because of Pythons moronic scoping rules).  In any
  case it'd better to make clear how that works.

That would be something the lines of the following then:

```
import csv

people = []
people_ids = set()

def add_person(group_id, new_subscription):
    people.append({
        'id': group_id,
        'subscriptions': [new_subscription]
    })
    people_ids.add(group_id)

#open csv file
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    csv_file = csv.reader(file)

    #read CSV file into a list of people
    for record in csv_file:
        sub_id = record[0]
        group_id = record[6]
        season_desc = record[11]
        series_desc = record[12]

        if "MW" in series_desc:
            sub_type = "Masterworks"
        elif "Pops" in series_desc:
            sub_type = "Pops"
        elif "Chamber" in series_desc:
            sub_type = "Chamber"

        new_subscription = {
            'id': sub_id,
            'season': season_desc,
            'sub_type': sub_type
        }

        #if this is the first time through the loop
        if len(people) == 0:
            add_person(group_id, new_subscription)
            continue

        #check if this person has already been recorded
        #if not, add the subscription to them and save the person
        if group_id not in people_ids:
            add_person(new_subscription)
            continue

        #check if this subscription has already been added to this person
        #use enumerate to get a key to search people
        for person in people:
            if person['id'] != group_id:
                person['subscriptions'].append(new_subscription)
```

I also shuffled the branches around, which together with `continue`
makes for less indented blocks.

If you're going to extend this, I'd recommend more factoring into functions, a
`main` function, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for a great response. I had already corrected a couple things you noticed. When I get back in front of my machine I will test this out and hopefully mark as an answer.

Comment: I haven't had time to debug, but it looks like this is adding some people to the list multiple times. It also seems to get stuck in a loop, and uses approx. 35X the memory as the original script. It does appear to be working faster until it gets stuck. EDIT - it is not counting people multiple times. I am looking for the memory use and will post a result. Definitely moving faster, so I am marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop:

```
if "MW" in series_desc:
    sub_type = "Masterworks"
elif "Pops" in series_desc:
    sub_type = "Pops"
elif "Chamber" in series_desc:
    sub_type = "Chamber"
```

becomes:

```
for type_ in ("MW", "Pops", "Chamber"):
    if type_ in series_disc:
        sub_type = type_
```

If as you say:

> The series description might have "MW" or "mw" or "Masterworks" or "masterworks." I need the type for all of those to be "Masterworks."

just use some tuples:

```
for types, to_write in ( ( ("MW","mw","Masterworks","masterworks"), "Masterworks"))):
    if any(t in series_disc for t in types):
         sub_type = to_write
```

Comment: My code is simplified. The series description might have "MW" or "mw" or "Masterworks" or "masterworks." I need the type for all of those to be "Masterworks."

Comment: @BrandonDorris Use a `dict` to map those to the same thing.